# Как определить сколько бит на одну точку в изображении формата BMP

Tags: изображения, bmp

Есть файл с изображением формата BMP. Просматриваю его в утилите HxD. Не понимаю, как определить 3 бита определенно под точку или 6.

Comment: форматов с тремя или шестью битами под точку не бывает.

Comment: Разделите размер файла на количество бит и посчитайте сходится ли с количеством точек.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, спасибо!

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev Размер bmp-файла 198 байт, 10x10. Можете продемонстрировать применение предложенного метода,

Comment: Вот картинка например - https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/bmp/bmp_24.bmp . Весит 117 килобайт. Площадь 200 x 200 = 40000 точек. 40000 * 24 бит = 960 000 бит. / 8 = 120 000 байт. / 1024 = 117 килобайт.

Comment: В вашей картинке возможно вшиты какие-то метаданные, или у неё 2 байта на точку, или размер не верный, или это не bmp. Нужно видеть картинку чтобы понять.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev Да нет, обычная 16-цветная иконка, уменьшенная до 10 пикселов. 4 бита на точку. А указанных автором форматов не существует.